# Include div tag into the focus of an input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So i have an input with a dropdown underneath. So when i click into an input the dropdown opens. But i can't select anything from the dropdown cause it is not focussed. So when i click on a value it doesnt get selected and the dropdown closes again because it looses focus. So i am now wondering how i can include the div into the focus of the input.

HTML input:

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control myInput" [(ngModel)]="textToSort"
(keyup)="onKeyDownAction($event)" (blur)="onBlurEventAction()" id="{{id}}" 
(focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="unFocusFunction()"/>
```

HTML div (dropdown):

```
<div class="data-container" *ngIf="showDropDown" style="position: absolute;" >
  <p 
  *ngFor="let data of dataList; let i = index" 
  class="data-list"                                 
  (click)="updateTextBox(i,data[columnName]); focusOnInput();" 
  [ngClass]="{highlight:checkHighlight(i)}"
  > {{data[columnName]}}</p>
</div>
```

Component:

```
focusFunction(){
    this.showDropDown = true;
  }
unFocusFunction() {
    this.showDropDown = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blur` event happens on your `input` because of `mousedown`on list item

So in order to prevent this you need to add

`(mousedown)="$event.preventDefault()"`

handler for your list items.
I created simple demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x3cdr1

Answer (score 0):

Have you in your CSS, tried setting the z-index to 1 for the dropdown class when it is expanded?

Please share a plunkr or a stackblitz link to look at the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be as follows:

```
focusFunction(){
   this.showDropDown = true;
}

unFocusFunction() {
  setTimeout(() => { this.showDropDown = false; }, 500);
}
```

I think checking this stackblitz would help also:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-search-filter?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts